# How do fix my gnome calendar?

Tags: 21.04, gnome-calendar

I wonder if some can help with my gnome calendar. I use it daily. I have create a duplicate entry on the calendar. Now when I open the calendar. it close by itself. I can not delete the duplicate off the calendar. I just want to delete the duplicate entry. Can someone help me with this issue please?

Thank
Marco

Comment: This sounds like a bug or some kind of corruption in the software. Can you try to back up your calendar and reinstall the software?  Consider filing a bug report

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @Nmath that this is likely a bug but you could try this first instead of a full reinstall:

```
$ vi ~/.local/share/evolution/calendar/system/calendar.ics
```

Each event should start with `BEGIN:VEVENT` and end with `END:VEVENT`. Just delete the duplicate event and save the file.

To force the calendar to reload:

```
$ ps -efa | grep calendar
$ kill <pid of gnome-shell-calendar-server> <pid of evolution-calendar-factory> <pid of gnome-calendar>
```

`gnome-shell-calendar-server` and `evolution-calendar-factory` should automatically respawn and when you start `gnome-calendar` it should reflect any changes you made to `calendar.ics`